# How to make child rows visible on clicking parent rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table in which there are parent rows and for every parent row, there are few child rows. I have to hide these child rows initially and when clicked on parent row, child rows should be shown.

I have a list of data and I am iterating through the list and for each iteration, I am appending the row to table like this.

```js
var json = [{
  Message: "abc",
  name: "Some name",
  id: 345,
  col4: 2,
  col5: 5
}];

var $container = $("#container");
var $thead = $("#container table thead");
var $tbody = $("#container table tbody");
var $row = $("#container table tbody tr");

json.forEach(function(item) {
  var $button = $("<button>" + item.Message + "</button>");
  $container.prepend($button);

  var table = $("<table>");
  table.append($("<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th></tr>"));

  $button.on("click", function() {
    //parent row
    var row = $('<tr><td>' + item.Message + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.name + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.id + '</td>' + '</td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');
    table.append(row);
    //child row
    var row = $('<tr><td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.col4 + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.col5 + '</td></tr>');
    table.append(row);

    $("#table").html(table);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="table">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to give an id to each parent row and class for child rows and when clicked on parent row child rows should be shown.

Comment: *"I have a html table"* <-- Doesn't look like you do. Looks like you have a `div` that you are appending `tr` tags to, which is incorrect. Also, with `tr` elements, they can't contain "child" `tr` elements. You'd need to nest an entire new table in the parent `tr`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sq9nr0xL/, this is the link of sample code, could you help me ?

Comment: `.parent` + [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

Comment: The name `json` for the variable is misleading as its content is an array of object(s) but _not_ [JSON](http://json.org)

Comment: do you mean "Accordion" or "collapse" https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/

Comment: collapse would be  great

Comment: Check the `.nextUntil()` link. There's an example that should be easily adjustable to fit your setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is give class to parent row and then toggle child rows based on jquery next function

```js
 var json = [{
     Message: "abc",
     name: "Some name",
     id: 345,
     col4:2,
     col5:5
 }];

 var $container = $("#container");
 var $thead = $("#container table thead");
 var $tbody = $("#container table tbody");
 var $row = $("#container table tbody tr");

 // Loop through items in JSON data..
 json.forEach(function(item) {
   var $button = $("<button>" + item.Message + "</button>");
   $container.prepend($button);
   var table = $("<table>");
   table.append($("<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th></tr>"));
          
  // Button click handler..
   $button.on("click", function() {
     
     // Replace row HTML..
     //parent row
     var row=$('<tr class="parent_row" ><td>' + item.Message + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.name + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.id + '</td>' + '</td>' +      "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');
     
     table.append(row);
     //child row
     var row=$('<tr style="display: none"><td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.col4 + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.col5 + '</td></tr>');
     table.append(row);
    
     $("#table").html(table);
      $('.parent_row').click(function() {
 
   $(this).next().toggle();
})
     // Show table if it's not already visible..
     

   });
 });
```

```css
table {
   margin-top: 20px;
   border: 1px solid silver;
   width: 500px;
 }

 th {
   text-align: left;
 }
 
 button {
   margin-left: 15px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="container">
   <div id="table">
   </div>

 </div>
```

in case you have more than one child than you can use [nextUntill('.parent_row')](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, I have one more question , if there are more parent rows and for every parent row, child rows are associated , then what should I do?

Comment: it does not matter how many parent rows you have next rows will select row depending on the element click as this refer to the parent click 
and if you have one than more child then you can use nextUntill in that case unless row dows not have parent class it will be toggled

Comment: no each parent have same class that is '.parent_row' but as i have said when you click a parent element variable this refer to that instance

Comment: I have an issue, could you please help , I have 2 for loops outer one for parent row and inner one for child rows, but when i click on parent row ,it shows child rows of its own and also child rows of all the parent rows following next to it.                           code goes like this-  for(     ){ //parent row                            
           table.append(parent row) { for( ) {                                                       //child rows   table.append(child rows) }}  $('.parent_row').click(function() {
   $(this).nextUntil(".parent").toggle(); })

Comment: you need  $(this).nextUntil(".parent_row").toggle(); rather than  $(this).nextUntil(".parent").toggle(); i hope it help